# Compare two Json objects with same keys and push into array- java

Tags: java, object

i have two json objects which has same keys

```
obj1 = {id:1,name:abc,rate:50}
obj2 = {id:1,name:abc,rate:100}
```

i want to compare two objs and push the keys into an array which have been modified

Comment: Add some code you have tried

Comment: You mean **replace** "obj1" with "obj2" in "array1" IF there is an update ?

Comment: This is not valid Java syntax. It looks like JSON objects. So is this question about how to do it in JavaScript or how to convert the JSON objects to Java objects and do the comparison there?

Comment: lol sorry.. i convert them to json before processing ..

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    String[] result = obj1.keySet().stream()
        .filter(k -> !obj1.get(k).equals(obj2.get(k)))
        .toArray(String[]::new);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
    // -> [rate]
```

Comment: not sure if its appropriate to suggest to a person new to java with new features of java8